# Неправильные ярлыки у значения атрибута в WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Создаю значение атрибута. В поле ярлык вместо того, чтобы как всегда, прописывать название значения только латиницей, вордпресс прописывает почему-то какие-то цифры. Как сделать, чтобы он нормально прописывал ярлык значения?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой плагин траслитерации стоит?

Comment: @KAGGDesign стоит обычный Cyr to Lat  но дело не в плагинах, вырубал все, и все равно не помогло